# Py3 ebay-scraper - Project I need cheap GPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need cheap GPU's and decided to make a little ebay-scraper to make sure I can buy it at cheap prices. It works and I can search for (any) product to scrape the Title, Price and Shipping cost of that product.

But I feel like I haven't done it in a generic way, hence the need to post it here. Thus my question is, could this have been done more generic?

---

**Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


def find_next_page(soup):
    '''
    Finds next page

    Returns:
        Next page link if exists
        None if next page does not exists
    '''
    next_page = soup.find('a', {'class': 'gspr next'})
    try:
        return next_page['href']
    except:
        return None


def scrape_page(soup, idx):
    '''
    Scrape page for products and save them as a dictionary

    Returns:
        A dictionary of products
    '''
    products = {}
    prod_idx = idx

    for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'id': 'ListViewInner'}):

        for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
            title = litag.find('a', {'class': 'vip'})
            if not title is None:
                products[prod_idx] = {}
                title_text = title.text
                if 'New listing' in title_text:
                    title_text = title_text.replace('New listing', '').lstrip()
                title_text.strip()
                products[prod_idx]['Title'] = title_text

            ul = litag.find('ul', {'class': 'lvprices left space-zero'})
            if not ul is None:
                for li in ul.find_all('li'):
                    if '$' in li.text and not 'shipping' in li.text.lower():
                        products[prod_idx]['Price'] = li.text.split()[0]
                    if 'shipping' in li.text.lower():
                        products[prod_idx]['Shipping'] = li.text.strip()

                prod_idx += 1
    return products, prod_idx


def table_print(products):
    '''
    Prints products in nice human-readable format
    '''
    print ("{:<8} {:<100} {:<15} {:<30}".format('Key', 'Product', 'Price', 'Shipping'))
    for k, v in products.items():
        try:
            t, p, s = v
            print ('{:<8} {:<100} {:<15} {:<30}'.format(k, products[k][t], products[k][p], products[k][s]))
        except ValueError:
            continue


def scrape_product(ebay_page):
    '''
    Main scraper
    '''
    products = {}
    idx = 0

    while not ebay_page is None:
        html_doc = urlopen(ebay_page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
        prod, idx = scrape_page(soup, idx)
        products.update(prod)
        ebay_page = find_next_page(soup)

    return products


def make_search_string(keywords):
    '''
    Make ebay search products string
    '''
    base = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw='
    end = '&_sacat=0'
    return '{0}{1}{2}'.format(base, '+'.join(keywords), end)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('Project I Need a Cheap GPU (Ebay-Scraper in Python3) \n@Ludisposed \n')
    keywords = input('What do you want to search ebay for? ').split()

    # Make search string
    ebay_page = make_search_string(keywords)

    # Find all products
    products = scrape_product(ebay_page)

    # Print all products
    table_print(products)
```

---

**Example**

```
Project I Need a Cheap GPU (Ebay-Scraper in Python3) 
@Ludisposed 

What do you want to search ebay for? amd 580
Key      Product                                                                                              Price           Shipping                      
0        XFX AMD Radeon RX 580 8GB GDDR5 GTR Black Edition PCI Express 3.0 New Sealed                         $305.00         +$37.83 shipping              
1        MSI AMD Radeon RX 580 GAMING X 4G GDDR5 DVI/2HDMI/2Displayport PCI-Express Video                     $336.99         +$46.19 shipping   
etc....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple things to improve, let's try to categorize them.

#### Code Style

- there is a number of [PEP8 code style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations, specifically:

  - documentations strings need to be enclosed into triple double quotes, start with a capital letter and end with a dot ([reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings))
  - [group imports properly](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)
- [handling a bare exception with `except:` is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797375/771848)
- when you check for a substring to be present in a string, you can use `not in`, e.g. `not 'shipping' in li.text.lower()` can be replaced with a more readable:

  ```
  'shipping' not in li.text.lower()
  ```
- I would also improve the way you format the search URL, extracting the base url as a constant and using `str.format()` to insert keywords into the URL:

  ```
  BASE_URL_TEMPLATE = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw={keywords}&_sacat=0'


  def make_search_string(keywords):
      """Constructs a search products string."""
      return BASE_URL_TEMPLATE.format(keywords='+'.join(keywords))
  ```

#### Web-Scraping and HTML Parsing

- if you would switch to [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) instead of `urllib`, you then can seriously improve on the performance of making the requests by re-using a [session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects):

  > ..if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase.
- `lxml` if used instead of `html.parser` can provide an HTML parsing performance boost as well
- see if using a [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) to focus your HTML parser on the desired part of the HTML tree only is also applicable in your scenario. It can further speed up the HTML parsing step
- using a [`LBYL` approach](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl) inside the `find_next_page` would be a bit more readable and concise:

  ```
  def find_next_page(soup):
      """
      Finds next page.

      Returns:
          Next page link if exists
          None if next page does not exists
      """
      next_page_link = soup.select_one('a.next')
      return next_page_link['href'] if next_page_link else None
  ```
- `scrape_page()` function is overly complicated. For instance, there is a single element with `id="ListViewInner"` on the page and it does not require a loop to locate this element. And, you can do better in locating elements on the page:

  ```
  def scrape_page(soup, index):
      """
      Scrapes page for products and save them as a dictionary.

      Returns:
          A dictionary of products
      """
      products = {}

      for produce_index, item in enumerate(soup.select('#ResultSetItems li'), index):
          title = item.select_one('a.vip')
          price = item.select_one(".prc")
          shipping_price = item.select_one('.ship')

          products[produce_index] = {
              'Title': title.find(text=True, recursive=False) if title else None,
              'Price': price.get_text(strip=True) if price else None,
              'Shipping': shipping_price.get_text(strip=True).split()[0] if shipping_price else None
          }

      return products, produce_index
  ```

  (not tested)

Also note the use of `enumerate()` for better handling enumeration (thanks @graipher for the idea).

Comment: I knew I was overcomplicating the `scrape_page()`.  + I tried it with `requests` but I failed somewhere, therefore I used something else to make it work... Damn this means I need to tinker with `bs4` some more.

Comment: @Graipher oh, good idea, completely missed that putting too much focus on the HTML parsing part :) Thanks!

Comment: And one more thing: Now it becomes really clear that `products` is just a structure which maps sequential integers starting at zero to some object. So it is basically a list and you don't need a `dict` at all. Just `append` to a list, or even better, make `scrape_page` a generator and then outside of it `extend` the list with it.

Comment: `enumerate` doesn't wotk well, because it scrapes empty products. So I have it outside and check if `title` is not `None`. If check passes I add 1 to avoid empty products. Secondly I like data structure as a dictionary to iterate only over `titles` for instance. With list it is also possible, but less readable imo.